# MissingPropertyException: No such property: * for class: java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry

Tags: grails, groovy

lets say i have this:

```
ArrayList maps = [ ]
Map map = [:]
```

my controller i did that:

```
List.each {
      myList -> map = [key1:value1,key2:value2,key3:value3]
        maps << map
    }
return render ( template: "myTemplate" , model: [arrayList:maps])
```

I'm passing this arrayList of maps to my GSP and iterating through it so i assign the values of each map to elements.

i did something like this in my gsp.

```
<g:each in="${arrayList}" var="map">
       <g:select  from="${someList}" optionValue="${map.get('key1')}" optionKey="key"/>
       <input type="text" id="textBox"  value="${map.get('key2')}"/>
        </g:each>
```

i am getting this error ! which says:

```
ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - MissingPropertyException occurred when processing request: [POST] .....

No such property: myValue for class: java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry. Stacktrace follows:
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: myValue  for class: java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry

at Users_**_Projects_**_grails_app_views__myGsp_gsp.run(_myGsp.gsp:6)
at org.grails.plugins.web.rest.api.ControllersRestApi.render(ControllersRestApi.groovy:53)
at se.su.it.vfu.ConfigController$$EPLhPshc.myFunction(myController.groovy:428)
```

myGsp.gsp:6: is actually the "select" row provided in the gsp code
and 428 in my controller is the return render () row

myValue is actually a map value!

I am iterating through the arrayList and the first map is map1 looks like this

```
[key1: myValue , key2: otherValue , key3 : someOtherValue]
```

Comment: What is `myValue`? where you have used `myValue`?

Comment: please provide more details or lines of code to further give details on your question

Comment: myValue should be the optionValue for the select! it actually is a map value for key1

Comment: your map[123] have syntax errors.  please make sure, that simplified code for the question still is valid

Comment: provided code samples are invalid and unrelated to provided exception. it's impossible to suggest anything w/o knowing real situation

Comment: the error results from something like this: [myValue: 42].each{ it.myValue }.  you are trying to get myValue from a map entry.  if you have maps in maps, then you would need it.value.myValue in that case

Comment: @cfrick can you elaborate more? myValue is a map value for key1. lets say the first map i iterate through is map1 = [key1: myValue , key2: otherValue , key3 : someOtherValue]

Comment: no it's just guesswork.  please provide a failing example, that actually makes sense, add the full stacktrace (or at least the most relevant parts) and correlate the line numbers from the stacktrace to code.

Comment: i edited the question with the full related stacktrace!

Comment: This question currently has a vote to close based on it not being about programming.  That doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

You have the following in your GSP:

```
<g:select  from="${someList}" optionValue="${map.get('key1')}" optionKey="key"/>
```

That is going to be the problem.  The value that you assign to `optionValue` should be the name of a property on the elements in `someList`.  That property will be used when generating the "value" of the individual elements in the list.  In your case it looks like `map.get('key1')` evaluates to `myValue` so the `select` tag is going to try and retrieve the value of the `myValue` property for each element in the list.

See http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.4/ref/Tags/select.html for more details.

I hope that helps.

Comment: by rendering the page i want to set the value of this select to a certain value which is the map.get('key1')! how can i do this then? "someList" is actually map of maps and myValue is a value of key there as well! thanks for help and sorry for making this complicated